# Event running even if the value is false

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

So, the issue is: the things occur even if the loadedFirst value is false. See:

```
var lastA = $(".feedpost-pages > a").last();
var pageToLoad = lastA.attr("href");
var lodadedFirst = false;

$(".loadold").click(function () {
  if (loadedFirst = true) {
    lastA = lastA.prev();
    var pageToLoad = lastA.attr("href");
    alert("this is happening, but the loadedFirst value is false. How?");
  }
  $.get(pageToLoad, function (data) {
    var postsContent = $(data).find(".post:not(:first)");
    $(".feedpost-lastreplys").prepend(postsContent);
    FormatPosts();
    FixPosts();
    countPosts();
    loadedFirst = true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is:

```
var lodadedFirst = false
//----^ Remove the d.
```

And the second one is:

```
if (loadedFirst = true) {
//--------------^ You are assigning and not comparing.
```

**Final**

```js
var lastA = $(".feedpost-pages > a").last();
var pageToLoad = lastA.attr("href");
var loadedFirst = false;

$(".loadold").click(function() {
  if (loadedFirst == true) {
    lastA = lastA.prev();
    var pageToLoad = lastA.attr("href");
    alert("this is happening, but the loadedFirst value is false. How?");
  }
  $.get(pageToLoad, function(data) {
    var postsContent = $(data).find(".post:not(:first)");
    $(".feedpost-lastreplys").prepend(postsContent);
    FormatPosts();
    FixPosts();
    countPosts();
    loadedFirst = true;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (loadedFirst = true)
```

to

```
if (loadedFirst == true)
```

You are assigning instead of comparing.